# Webmock and VCR, allow Http Connections if there is no cassette

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines, vcr, webmock

I have a problem, I can run a test that uses vcr on its own and it works, it creates the cassette and it uses that on the next test. Great.

The problem is when I run all my tests together this particular test fails, because webmock disables http connections, I have seen [this example on the Github repo page that explains how to expect real and not stubbed requests](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#expecting-real-not-stubbed-requests)

My question is how Do I say: **Allow Http connections for requests UNLESS there is a cassette. It should also CREATE the cassette when HTTP connections are allowed.**

#### The VCR Settings

```
require 'vcr'

VCR.configure do | c |
  if !ARGV.first.nil?
    c.default_cassette_options = { :record => :new_episodes, :erb => true }
    c.filter_sensitive_data('<BLACKBIRD_API_KEY>') {YAML.load(File.read('config/application.yml'))['BLACKBIRD_API_KEY'].to_s}
    c.filter_sensitive_data('<BLACKBIRD_API_URL>') {YAML.load(File.read('config/application.yml'))['BLACKBIRD_API_URL'].to_s}
    c.debug_logger = File.open(ARGV.first, 'w')
    c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/vcr'
    c.hook_into :webmock
  end
end
```

the above if statement exists because not EVERY test creates a cassette. So we want them to run when a cassette isn't needed.

#### The Test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Xaaron::Publishers::Users do

  context "publish created users" do
    before(:each) do
      Xaaron.configuration.reset
      no_user_member_roles_relation

      Xaaron.configuration.publish_to_black_bird = true
      Xaaron.configuration.black_bird_api_url = YAML.load(File.read('config/application.yml'))['BLACKBIRD_API_URL']
      Xaaron.configuration.black_bird_api_key =YAML.load(File.read('config/application.yml'))['BLACKBIRD_API_KEY']
    end

    it "should publish to blackbird" do
      VCR.use_cassette 'publisher/create_user_response' do
        expect(
          Xaaron::Publishers::Users.publish_new_user({user: {
            first_name: 'adsadsad', user_name: 'sasdasdasdsa'  ,
            email: 'asdassad@sample.com', auth_token: 'asdsadasdasdsa'
          }}).code
        ).to eql 200
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Runs fine on its own, creates the cassette, fails when run with all other tests due to webmock.

#### The Failure

```
Failure/Error: Xaaron::Publishers::Users.publish_new_user({user: {
 WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
   Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET some_site_url_here with headers {'Http-Authorization'=>'api_key_here', 'User-Agent'=>'Typhoeus - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus'}

   You can stub this request with the following snippet:

   stub_request(:get, "some site url here").
     with(:headers => {'Http-Authorization'=>'some api key here', 'User-Agent'=>'Typhoeus - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus'}).
     to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```